# Migrate Module and AddressField Locality/City Lookup in PrepareRow Fails

Tags: migrations, entities

I'm running a migration to move volunteers from a csv file to drupal.  I have written the following code.

```
<?php
/**
    * @file
    * Migration for Volunteer File 
*/

ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

class VolunteerMigration extends Migration {

public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->description = t('Imports Volunteers from CSV file ');

    // Create a source object
    $columns = array(
        0 => array('pkid', 'PKID'),
        1 => array('fname', 'First Name'),
        2 => array('lname', 'Last Name'),
        3 => array('email','Email'),
        5 => array('dayphone','DayPhone'),
        6 => array('eveningphone','EveningPhone'),
        7 => array('address','Address'),
        8 => array('city', 'City'),
        9 => array('state','State'),
        10 => array('postalcode','zip'),
        11 => array('occupation','Occupation'),
        12 => array('interests','Interests'),
        13 => array('created','Timestamp'),
    );
    $address_arguments = array(
        'first_name' => array('source_field' => 'fname'),
        'last_name' => array('source_field' => 'lname'),
        'thoroughfare' => array('source_field' => 'address'),
        'locality' => array('source_field' => 'city'),
        'administrative_area' => array('source_field'=>'state'),
        'postal_code' => array('source_field' => 'postalcode'),
    );
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV('/mnt/www/cylindrical/theoregonproject.com/data/drvollist.csv', $columns, array('header_rows' => 1));

    // Create a destination object
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('volunteers');

    // Create a map
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap(
        $this->machineName,
        array(
            'pkid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
        ),
        MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(),
        'campaign_migration'
    );

    // Create Mappings
    $this->addFieldMapping('title', NULL)->DefaultValue('Volunteer');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_volunteer_address')
        ->arguments($address_arguments);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_volunteer_id', 'pkid');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_email', 'email');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_dayphone', 'dayphone');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_eveningphone', 'eveningphone');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_occupation', 'occupation');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_interests', 'interests')
            ->separator(',');
    $this->addFieldMapping('created','created');

}

public function prepareRow($row) {

    if ( $row->zip ) { 
        $row->city = zipcity($row->zip);
    }
}

public function zipcity($zip) {
    $ch = curl_init('http://ziptasticapi.com/' . $zip);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($result,true);

    return $json['city'];
}
}
?>
```

I'm am using the [ziptastic api](http://ziptasticapi.com/) to fill in the cities using the zipcode.  Running the migration returns all except the address portion of the migration.  The zipcity function works as expected (returns city given a zipcode) but none of the address arguments are migrated.

I have adapted this code from a previous and successful migration minus the preparerow / zipcity additions.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  When using the addressfield module, you should have field mappings that allow for preparerow to work.  I thought that the address_arguments array was enough to create the field maps.  Also I was using the csv column title 'Zip' instead of the the mapped field title 'postalcode'

Under my address field mapping I added the following code.

```
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'fname');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'lname');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'address');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'city');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'state');
    $this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'postalcode');
```

I also moved the function zipcity to my helper function file to allow other migrations to use it if needed.

This post https://drupal.org/node/1326044 was key into figuring out the missing link.